# Unable to download the image

Tags: python, urllib

I want to download the two images in the webpage with selenium:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.anjuke.com/captcha-verify/?callback=shield&from=antispam&serialID=dbd7496ee02aa06b')

img_url = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='dvc-captcha__bgImg']").get_attribute('src')
icon_url = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='dvc-captcha__puzzleImg']").get_attribute('src')
```

You may set img_url = 'https://verifycode.58.com/captcha/captcha_img?rid=d08cf4028d814d55af0e8e5ef9cb00ed&it=_big'

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url )
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
# result : array([], dtype=uint8)
```

Finally, I got an empty array.

Why did it happen?

How to get the array?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The method i use is with the `requests` library as follows:

```
import requests

with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(requests.get(img_url).content)
```

here, `requests.get(url).content` returns the contents of the webpage by accessing the URL provided. 
Which in this case is the image.

The image is then written to a file `image.jpg` which is opened as `wb`.

you can replicate this for your other image too i.e. `icon_url`

Another way is to use the `imageio` package as follows:

```
import imageio

image = imageio.imread(img_url)
```

the `image` var is just a extension of the numpy array and you can manupilate it as such. Here, the `img_url` is just a url string to your image.

Comment: Thank you BrownBatman. However, it does not work. As `img_url` from the webpage `https://www.anjuke.com/captcha-verify/?callback=shield&from=antispam&serialID=dbd7496ee02aa06b'` is not the real url of the image, it is more complicated than expected.